Помогите как сделать переменную глобальной Python
import random

while vopros == "da":

    Player1 = random.randint(1, 6)
    print("Первому игроку выпало число:")
    print(Player1)

    Player2 = random.randint(1,6)
    print("Второму игроку выпало число:")
    print(Player2)

    if Player1 > Player2:
        print("Первый Игрок Победил!")

    if Player1 < Player2:
        print("Второй Игрок Победил!")

    elif Player1 == Player2:
        print("Ничья!")

    vopros = input("Продолжить? da/net: ")

    break


    print("")

Что не так с моим кодом

Чему равна переменная vopros при самом первом выполнении строчки while vopros == "da"?

Тема вопроса вообще не отражает сути вопроса.

import random
vopros = "da"
while vopros == "da":

    Player1 = random.randint(1, 6)
    print("Первому игроку выпало число:")
    print(Player1)

    Player2 = random.randint(1,6)
    print("Второму игроку выпало число:")
    print(Player2)

    if Player1 > Player2:
        print("Первый Игрок Победил!")

    if Player1 < Player2:
        print("Второй Игрок Победил!")

    elif Player1 == Player2:
        print("Ничья!")

    vopros = input("Продолжить? da/net: ")
    if vopros == "net":
        break


    print("")

У вас переменная была изначально не объявлена из-за чего интерпретатор и выдает ошибку что переменной не существует.Этот код теперь работает как скорее всего вы и хотели)

Спасибо вам огромное

Компилятор, серьёзно?

@Глеб это образно

Ну, у питона немножко интерпретатор. Я это имел в виду...

@коля Для того, чтобы отметить ответ принятым, нажмите на серую галку рядом с ответом. Галка станет зелёной. Это будет означать, что ответ отмечен как решение вопроса. Вы можете в любой момент снять галку или отметить ею другой ответ.
